# Caratheodory: Construction

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory, definition

Given a semiring.

Consider a premeasure.

Regard the following constructions:
$$\inf_{A\subseteq S_1\sqcup\ldots\sqcup S_n}\{\mu(S_1)+\ldots+\mu(S_n)\}\quad\inf_{A\subseteq\bigsqcup_kS_k}\sum_k\mu(S_k)\quad\inf_{A\subseteq\bigcup_kS_k}\sum_k\mu(S_k)$$
Do these differ and which are still subadditive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This answer is not up-to-date...*

Consider the finite integral measure:
$$\mu(E):=\int_Ee^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}x:\quad\mu(\mathbb{R})=\sqrt{\pi}$$
Take the ring of bounded Borel sets:
$$E\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}):\quad|E|<\infty$$

Then the first differs from the latter both:
$$\mu_0(\mathbb{R})=\infty\neq\sqrt{\pi}=\mu_{12}(\mathbb{R})$$

It also fails to be subadditive:
$$\mu_0(\mathbb{R})=\infty\nleq\sqrt{\pi}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\mu_0(k,k+1]$$
*(This even prohibits it from becoming a measure at all!)*

The latter both agree since:
$$S=(S\setminus S')\sqcup(S\cap S')=(S_1\sqcup\ldots\sqcup S_n)\sqcup(S\cap S')$$
*(That gives among other subadditivity.)*

Comment: nice I needed something like this